# Cookie not expiring in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

In every other tested browser (safari, firefox, chrome, opera) the cookie is alive when user is on page and when the browser or tab is closed or the cookie expires after 5 seconds. In IE it only expires when closing IE completely but not when just closing a tab.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (/(^|;)\s*testcookie=/.test(document.cookie)) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hello again user";
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){document.cookie = "testcookie=true; max-age=" + 5 * 1 + ";path=/"},1000);
} else {
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){document.cookie = "testcookie=true; max-age=" + 5 * 1 + ";path=/"},1000);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "welcome new user";
}
</script>
```

A jsfiddle for thos who want that: http://jsfiddle.net/JkceP/

Kind regards
Johan

Comment: A quick Google search reveals that, at least in older IE, `max-age` is simply not supported – not sure whether that’s _still_ the case, but try with `expires` and an accordingly formated date instead.

Comment: According to my Google search this is the case for IE 8 but not later versions... any suggestions on how expires could be implemented? I tried without any luck so far. Thank you for the help!